# Android data binding with custom adapter

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm trying to use [Android's Data Binding features](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) with a custom adapter and a ListView. I'm having trouble overriding the custom adapter's `getView` method:

```
public class ChecksAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Check> {

    public ChecksAdapter(Context context, ObservableList<Check> checks) {
        super(context, R.layout.check, checks);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CheckBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(getContext()),
                R.layout.check, parent, false);
        binding.setCheck(this.getItem(position));

        // Return what?
    }
    
}
```

So my questions are:

- Where do I get the `View` element that I should be returning? Or in other words, how can I bind the object to an inflated/converted view?
- How can I reuse `convertView` when using data binding?
- Is this the correct way to implement this? The guide is not very clear on ListViews

Here's the only reference of ListViews in the guide:

> If you are using data binding items inside a ListView or RecyclerView adapter, you may prefer to use:
>
> ```
>    ListItemBinding binding = ListItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, viewGroup, false);
>    //or
>    ListItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
> ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html), you should return `binding.getRoot()`.

```
View getRoot ()
```

> Returns the outermost View in the layout file associated with the
>   Binding. If this binding is for a merge layout file, this will return
>   the first root in the merge tag.

Answer (score 28):

You should do the following for smooth scrolling though..

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CheckBinding binding;
    if(convertView == null) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(getContext()),
                R.layout.check, parent, false);
        convertView = binding.getRoot();
    }
    else {
        binding = (CheckBinding) convertView.getTag();
    }

    binding.setCheck(this.getItem(position));
    convertView.setTag(binding);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: i don't know why but this is not working for me when i am using a cursor adapter

Comment: @sergi why are you checking if the convertView is null?

Comment: @Thalatta the first time that row is displayed the `convertView.getTag()` will return a `null` object because it has never been initialized.
The code in the `if` branch will only be executed as initialization the first time the visible rows are displayed. As you scroll, the `else` branch will be reached.

Answer (score 5):

For completes here is the kotlin variant:

```
    val binding = convertView?.tag as? CheckBinding ?: CheckBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
    binding.check = this.getItem(position)
    binding.root.tag = binding

    return binding.root
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Recommended way

Use generated Binding class instead of DataBindingUtil class. See [Documentation.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding#java)

> If you are using data binding items inside a `Fragment`, `ListView`, or
>   `RecyclerView` adapter, you may prefer to use the `inflate()` methods of
>   the bindings classes

### Use

```
binding = CheckBinding.inflate(this, parent, false);
```

### instead of

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(getContext()),
                R.layout.check, parent, false);
```

Other code will be same as @sergi

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CheckBinding binding;
    if(convertView == null) {
        binding = CheckBinding.inflate(this, parent, false);
        convertView = binding.getRoot();
    }
    else {
        binding = (CheckBinding) convertView.getTag();
    }

    binding.setCheck(this.getItem(position));
    convertView.setTag(binding);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: When I use this approach, I often get lint warnings indicating `R.layout.check` appears to be unused. Hence, I prefer to use `DataBindingUtil `

Answer (score 1):

```
ItemTickFilterBinding mFilterBinding;

    if (convertView==null) {
        mFilterBinding= DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(mContext),
                R.layout.item_tick_filter, parent, false);
        convertView.setTag(mFilterBinding);
    }
    else {
        mFilterBinding=(ItemTickFilterBinding)convertView.getTag();
    }
```

Comment: in base adapter's method getView .mFilterBinding  is the instance of listrow layout and u should set tag on convert view and get in else part also.

Answer (score 0):

DataBindingUtil will save the ViewDataBinding object to view.tag, so you can retrieve it later by DataBindingUtil.getBinding(convertView)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getViewForResource(mResourceId, position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getViewForResource(mDropDownResourceId, position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getViewForResource(int resourceId, int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewDataBinding binding = (convertView != null) ? DataBindingUtil.getBinding(convertView) : DataBindingUtil.inflate(mLayoutInflater, resourceId, parent, false);
    binding.setVariable(BR.viewModel, getItem(position));
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For GridView adapters or custom adapter following code worked for me :

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, container: ViewGroup?): View {
    val binding = convertView?.tag as? MenuItemBinding ?:
    MenuItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(ctx), container, false)

    val menuItem = menuList[position]
    binding.txtVw.text = menuItem.title
    binding.imgVwIcon.setImageResource(menuItem.iconId)
    return binding.root
}
```

MenuItemBinding is on the basis of the name of the layout file here the layout file name is **'menu_item.xml'**.