# Unconditional layout inflation from view adapter warning

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using GridView in my alert dialogue with below codes.its giving me error called in title. My codes and more required information is like below.

```
  private void showGotoPageDialog() {

        final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.grid_dialogue);
        mDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        GridView mGridView = (GridView) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.grid_dialog);
        ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>(mPageOptions.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < mPageOptions.length; i++)
        {
            tmp.add(mPageOptions[i].split(" ")[1]);
        }
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), tmp, mPageIndx);
        //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tmp);
        mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int item, long l) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                mPageIndx = item + 1;
                updateQuotesListServer();
                updatePageInfo();
            }
        });
        mDialog.show();
        TextView dismiss = (TextView) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_dismiss);
        dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

and Adapter like this

```
 private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private ArrayList<String> list;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private int currentPage;

        CustomAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> list, int currentPage)
        {
            this.list = new ArrayList<>();
            this.list.addAll(list);
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            this.currentPage = currentPage;
        }

        public void setCurrentPage(int currentPage)
        {
            this.currentPage = currentPage;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            view = View.inflate(getActivity(),R.layout.dialogue_item, null);
            TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_dialogue);
            txt.setText(list.get(i));
            if(i == currentPage-1)
            {
                txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }

            return view;
        }
    }
```

its giving me warning on this line

```
view = View.inflate(getActivity(),R.layout.dialogue_item, null);
```

warning is like below

```
Unconditional layout inflation from view adapter: Should use View Holder pattern (use recycled view passed into this method as the second parameter) for smoother scrolling.
```

My code is working fine as expected and I am not facing any issue. `I want know that What changes require for fix this and what is benefit of it ?` Let me know if someone can help me for come out from this and solve my doubt.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

View adapter is built so that instead of creating a new view for each item, views that scroll off screen can be reused (they are passed in via the 2nd argument of getView). You are being warned that you should try to reuse these views instead of *always* inflating new ones. Change the line to

```
if (view == null) view = View.inflate(getActivity(),R.layout.dialogue_item, null);
```

Comment: if I use like this then warning is gone but getting crashed with this error **ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)'** on line **TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_dialogue);**

Comment: @Priya There was a typo before. Try again.

Comment: its working fine...Thanks a lot for solve my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
view = View.inflate(R.layout.dialogue_item, viewGroup, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If not necessary, in other words if view is not null, then it is not necessary to call the following line in getView() method :

```
view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.spinner_rect, null);
```

the problem arises the same wrong source code available on the web:
https://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-spinner-examples.html
https://demonuts.com/android-custom-spinner-image/
apply my solution for correctness

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for useful answers: I had the same error but I was using view binding. Resolved using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51719884/3340706) approach.